# When is casting/instanceof a good use?

Tags: oop, polymorphism, domain-driven-design

Every time I google instanceof and casting I will always see answers saying to avoid it and use X pattern.

I have an example where I can't see any pattern I think I could use.

We have 2 classes: Order and Payment (CashPayment and CardPayment).

CashPayment has 1 property called `amount` and and an implemented method `pay`.

CardPayment has 1 property called `cardNumber` and an implemented `pay` that calls 3rd party API.

Now say you would like to compose a view about an Order, how would someone avoid using instanceof or casting here to show the payment details?

With instanceof I can do this:

```
order = new Order(...);
order.checkout(aPayment);

Payment Details (Cash):
Type: (instanceof CashPayment ? "Cash") or order.payment().type();
Amount: ((CashPayment) order.payment()).amount();

Payment Details (Card):
Type: (instanceof CardPayment ? "Card") or order.payment().type();
Card Number: ((CardPayment) order.payment()).cardNumber();
```

**Question**: can we really avoid instanceof and casting? If yes, how can we achieve this the "OO-way"? If no, I assume this is one of the valid cases?

IMO, we can avoid instanceof/casting and favor use of overridden methods however if you want to know about a concrete object it can't be avoided.

**Edit:**

I am trying to write my Domain Models which means it is agnostic of infrastructure and application specific stuff.

Imagine we would need to save the Order thru OrderRepository and the Payment has their own tables. Wouldn't it be ugly if it was like:

```
class OrderRepository {
  public function save(Order order) {
    // Insert into order query here...
    // Insert into orderItems query here...
    // Insert payment into its table

    queryBuilder
      .table(order.payment().tableName())
      .insert([
        order.payment().columnName() => order.payment().value()
      ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely want to segregate the operation from the object itself (e.g. to maintain separation of concerns), but the operation is strongly coupled to subclass details then you only have two choices.

You either need to rethink the model and find an homogeneous abstraction, which could be any approach that allows you to treat the various types the same way.

e.g.

```
Payment Details:
Type: {{payment.type}}
{{for attr in payment.attributes}}
    {{attr.name}}: {{attr.value}}
{{/}}
```

or you need to perform some kind of type matching, whether you are using the visitor pattern, pattern matching, `instanceof`, etc.

e.g. with the [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

```
interface IPaymentVisitor {
    public void visit(CashPayment payment);
    public void visit(CardPayment payment);
}

class PaymentRenderer implements IPaymentVisitor ...

class CashPayment extends Payment {
   ...
   public void visit(IPaymentVisitor visitor) {
       visitor.visit(this);
   }
}

var renderer = new PaymentRenderer(outputStream);
payment.accept(renderer);
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious object-oriented solution is to add a `display()` method to the `Payment`.

In general instanceof/casting is frowned upon, because it usually indicates a less then optimal design. The only time where it is allowed is when the type-system is not powerful enough to express something. I encountered a few situations in Java where there is no better solution (mostly because there are no read-only collections in Java, therefore the generic parameter is invariant), none in Scala or Haskell yet.

Comment: `display` might work. I think the example I wrote was tied to UI but that's the easiest example I can come up with. The context I had in my mind was Domain Models where it only contains business logic and agnostic of whatever would use it. Will update the question

Comment: How to persist or present an object will always by definition depend on object internals. These behaviors are *cohesive* to the object. I don't subscribe to the idea that objects should be "agnostic" of functions that are highly cohesive to them.

Answer (score 0):

You could go with *composition* over *inheritance*.

Perhaps something along the lines of:

```
public class Payment
{
    private CardPaymentDetail _cardPaymentDetail;

    public PaymentType Type { get; private set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; }

    private Payment(decimal amount)
    {
        // > 0 guard

        Amount = amount;
    }

    private Payment(decimal amount, CardPaymentDetail cardPayment)
        : this(amout)
    {
        // null guard

        CardPayment = cardPayment;
    }

    public CardPaymentDetail CardPayment
    {
        get 
        {
            if (Type != PaymentType.Card)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("This is not a card payment.");
            }

            return _cardPaymentDetail;
        }
    }
}
```

IMHO persistence may also be easier.  Along the same lines I have also used what equates to an `Unknown` payment type as the default and then have a method to specify the type: `AsCard(CardPaymentDetail cardPayment) { }`.

Comment: I'm sorry maybe I'm just not familiar with this language but Card has cardNumber and Cash has amount or how much was given so the change can be computed; card does not need that. Given you are interested with different properties, how do you solve that? Have methods cardDetails, cashDetails, maybe even paypalDetails which returns null if it's not applicable to them?

Comment: I would have different `*Detail` value object for each grouping of data.  When paying you typically are paying an `Amount` along with `Tax` and so forth which is why I'd have it on the `Payment` but if it is only going to apply to certain types then that would be split out.  When persisting you would want all the relevant details anyway which is why that bit, in my opinion, becomes easier to manage also.  I used C# here as an example.

Comment: That will require instanceof still, no? if instanceof CardDetails, details.cardNumber() else if instanceof CashDetails, details.cashAmount(), else.... So on.

Comment: I don't think `instanceof` would be required.  You'll have a property for each `PaymentType` on the `Payment` and use the 'Type` property on the `Payment` to access/set the relevant payment detail.  There isn't going to be an inherited detail class per type.  You *could* have some interface, as has been stated by Robert, that exposes something like a `display()` method but you would have to decide just how useful that is going to be.  I would still work with the individual types since they are truly distinct; else you are going to be downcasting.